# Opening pdfs on firefox in a new tab

Tags: pdf, big-sur, firefox

Using Firefox 86.0 on Big Sur 11.2 and I am trying to find out how to immediately open pdfs in a new tab on firefox when I am given the option to download them. This option was available as the first option on my previous windows computer under "Open with firefox" which automatically opens the pdf in a new tab.
[image]

However now all I get is this and even when I navigate to "other.." and select Firefox, a new Firefox window is launched instead of a tab.
[image]

Any fixes for this?

Answer (score 1):

Open Firefox preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) and select appropriat(e) choice(s) under 'Tab'. Functionality you are looking for is 'Open links in tabs instead of new windows' (but others may or may not be helpful as well). If this is selected clicking on link to pdf file will open it in a new tab:

[image]

Comment: This is already checked for me but PDFs still open for me in a new browser window. Just to clarify, PDFs already open in a new tab when I click directly on a .pdf link, however the problem I am describing is for when I try to download a pdf file

Comment: If pdf already opened in Firefox tab then `⌘`+`S` opens "Save As" dialog. If there is link to pdf on webpage then hover over link and press two fingers on touchpad (or `⌃`+click, same as 'right click' in  Windows) which opens menu and select "Save Link As..." which opens "Enter name of file to save to..."